# How to interpolate the properties in gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am trying to achieve the following use-case through gradle. I have a properties file which consists of some hundreds of properties. For sample purpose, let us take the values something like this

```
a=mnop
b=${a}/xyz
c=${b}/abc
d=${c}/pqr
```

The use-case i want to achieve here through either gradle/groovy is that, this property file (say test.properties) should be copied to another file (test-output.properties) with the values replaced as follows.

```
a=mnop
b=mnop/xyz
c=mnop/xyz/abc
d=mnop/xyz/abc/pqr
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create your properties file as mentioned below (See quotes around)

   a="mnop"

   b="${a}/xyz"
2. Use `ConfigSlurper` to parse the properties file as:

   def con = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('config.properties').toURL())

Now `con.b` should print `mnop/xyz`